# Display content in two columns using html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display content in two columns in HTML5. But, somehow, I am doing something wrong. Here's my HTML code

```css
.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cd-admin-upper-container container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column1">
      <h1>Device UnAssignment</h1>
      <div>
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="height : 50%; margin-bottom : 2vw;width: 40%">
          <label class="cd-admin-create-modal-label">Patient Name: </label>
          <label class="cd-admin-create-modal-label">Device Serial Number: </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 3%"
          ng-click="unassignDevice(device.patientId);"><span title="UnAssign Device"></span> UnAssign
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <h1>Device Assignment</h1>
        <p>Hello this is column two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/chandham/k39vpafd/

Comment: `.column2` is nested within `column1`

Comment: Oh, Thanks. silly mistake!

Comment: No problem, chan - you should just close the question.

Comment: how to close the question?

Comment: It seems you need at least 250 rep points to close your own question (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question), but you should still be able to delete it, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question

Answer (score -1):

I somehow nested column1 and column2 in same div. Here's the updated code.

```html
<div class="cd-admin-upper-container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1">
            <h1>Device UnAssignment</h1>
            <div class="alert alert-info" style="height : 50%; margin-bottom : 2vw;width: 40%">
                <label class="cd-admin-create-modal-label">Patient Name: </label>
                <label class="cd-admin-create-modal-label">Device Serial Number: </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 3%" ng-click="unassignDevice(device.patientId);"><span title="UnAssign Device"></span> UnAssign
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <h1>Device Assignment</h1>
            <p>Hello this is column two</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it an answer to your own question or an edit to the question ? Because it still doesn't work.

Comment: When I run the code snippet, i don’t see the 2 columns next to each other, that’s why i ask. Instead, i see column 2 below column 1. Maybe i didn’t understand what you want to achieve.